# JQuery Plugin - Sort nested lists between two lists

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, nested-lists

So, I need to drag and drop between two nested lists. A sort of combination of this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

and this: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Is there something that already does this, or should I try to use these at the same time, somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use jQuery UI's `connectWith` option on the `nestedSortable` plugin, since the latter is just an extension of the default jQuery UI sortable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Ge7eK/9/

**JavaScript code:**

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    /* … Options for nestedSortable … */
    connectWith: '.sortable'
});​
```

Comment: FYI, this is not working in IE9 because IE requested a content type of `application/javascript` and github returned `text/plain` for `jquery.ui.nestedSortable.js` so it got blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery ui solution can handle nested lists:
http://jsfiddle.net/wyV7f/3/

If you need anything more than that perhaps you can hack it in?

Comment: This isn't what's being asked for. In the OP's second link, you can sort sub-items as well.

Comment: So, with that I can't change the nesting levels. So, I can't take something from the sublist of one thing and put it at the sublist of another, etc. I suppose I could hack it in, but I was hoping someone else had done this sort of thing, already.